# Automated testing tool for ASP.Net Web Site

Tags: asp.net, testing

Can Somebody know the **FREE** Automated Testing Tool for testing asp.net website 
which tests the security , connection pooling etc. i used netsparker community edition but it has very limited features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ASAFAWEB](http://asafaweb.com/) is a good tool to scan your website for common security vulnerabilities. It isn't really an automated testing tool, but just something that is good to do before going live to make sure you have crossed your T's and dotted your I's.

I'd also recommend reading his [ebook](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/12/free-ebook-owasp-top-10-for-net.html) to have a more thorough understanding of the most common security vulnerabilities and how to mitigate them with ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks can we test dos attacks on that site